# How to resolve outof memory at line no in IE8

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are getting out of memory in IE8 when using highcharts:

[image]

how to findout memory leaks in java and javascript in webapplication(particularly internet explorer)???

Thanks in advance for help...!

Comment: here is my image link [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3vbsr.jpg

Comment: GOTO Line number 2545

Comment: 1) Is that in your script or theirs (Highcharts)? 2) You can use the F12 developer tools to profile hotspots in your application; Chrome's tools have more detailed output (which can be useful to locate an issue, even if you aren't seeing it in Chrome). 3) Java has nothing to do with this (this is JavaScript).

Comment: Thnkq Medora, i checked more information finding out memoryleaks in chrome and ie, but i want to know where its happening.

Comment: Do you have the newest Highchats 3.0 ?